# Recursive Algorithm for a space filling Hilbert Curve in java

Tags: java, recursion

I am learning to code in Java and I have gotten to the recursion portion of java programming.  I understand the basics of what goes into a recursive method, and am trying to code a space filling Hilbert curve (and a Levy C curve) and so far everything has been smooth sailing until the actual recursion part.  I am having trouble coming up with the recursive method and would like to know if anyone could help me out.  Also I know it needs to be in the DrawHilbert method.

```
public class HilbertCurve extends JPanel {
int N;

/**
 * Constructor for Hilbert Curve
 */
public HilbertCurve () 
{
    Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer number to indicate the level of recursive depth: ");
    N = myKeyboard.nextInt();
    // Create a JFrame - a window that will appear on your screen
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    // Tells the program to quit if you close the window
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // Puts your drawing into the window (the JFrame)
    f.add(new JScrollPane(this));
    // Changes the size of the window on the screen
    f.setSize(600, 600);
    // Changes where the window will appear on your screen
    f.setLocation(200, 200);
    // Makes the window appear
    f.setVisible(true);
}
public void setupHilbert (Turtle turtle) 
{
    turtle.penup();
    turtle.setXY(0,0);

    // draw a simple rectangle that is 100x50 pixels
    turtle.pendown();

    drawHilbert(turtle, N); 
}

public void drawHilbert(Turtle turtle, int n) {

    if (n == 0) return;
    turtle.changeColor(Color.GREEN);
    turtle.changeWidth(2);
    turtle.left(-90);
    turtle.forward(100);
    turtle.left(90);
    turtle.forward(100);
    turtle.left(90);
    turtle.forward(100);
    turtle.left(-90);
    turtle.penup();
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Turtle turtle = new Turtle((Graphics2D) g, getBounds());

    turtle.setHeadingMode(Turtle.DEGREE);
    setupHilbert(turtle);

}


// plot a Hilbert curve of order N
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    HilbertCurve test = new HilbertCurve();
}
```

}

Comment: Funny thing is that there is also iterative algorithm for drawing Hilbert curve not much more difficult that recursive method: https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/iterative-algorithm-for-drawing-hilbert-curve

Answer (score 1):

The telltale sign of recursion is a function calling itself.  I would expect to see a call to `drawHilbert()` inside itself somewhere, but I don't.

Pay close attention to your stopping condition or you'll end up with an OutOfMemoryError as your recursive calls add to the stack forever.

I'm not familiar with your problem, but would this be what you're missing?

```
public void drawHilbert(Turtle turtle, int n) {

    if (n == 0) return;
    turtle.changeColor(Color.GREEN);
    turtle.changeWidth(2);
    turtle.left(-90);
    turtle.forward(100);
    turtle.left(90);
    turtle.forward(100);
    turtle.left(90);
    turtle.forward(100);
    turtle.left(-90);
    turtle.penup();
    drawHilbert(turtle, --n);  // is this where your recursion should go?
}
```

Update: This site looks pertinent.

http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/fu-intr-2_themes-hilbert-sec.html

Comment: Ok, that is true.  Calling itself is one of the 3 components to a recursive function.  So I added this: 

if (n == 0) return;

  turtle.changeColor(Color.BLUE);

  turtle.changeWidth(2);

  turtle.left(-90);

  drawHilbert(turtle, N-1);

  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.left(90);
  drawHilbert(turtle, N-1);
  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.left(90);
  drawHilbert(turtle, N-1);
  turtle.forward(100);
  turtle.left(-90);
  turtle.penup();'

but that doesn't seem to work.  Am I closer

Comment: I don't know - I'd have to understand your problem better.  N-1 doesn't look right to me, because you have to subtract from the parameter n that you pass in.  Java's case sensitive, so "n" and "N" are different variable names.

Comment: Don't apologize; you're learning and putting in a fine effort. Take a look at the link I posted.  I think it'll spell out where the recursion fits in.

Comment: you're right. I am sorry. As you can see I am new at this. So I changed the n to N. that is the instance variable that denotes the level of recursion (or recursive depth) that I want the program to display.  So N = 1, would be the base case, then 2,3,4 and so on would be more space filling.  

when I changed the n to N, the program runs, but just changes the position of the base case by 90 degrees clockwise but does not add recursive depth.

Comment: This is where a deeper understanding of your problem will come in handy.  Remember that every recursive call can be expressed as an iterative one, and visa versa.  Get your code to work with a loop implementation first, then worry about recursion.